# Question on pyspark data frame for timestamp

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe in which one of the column is a time stamp.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njjMh.png)

How can i create another data frame from this column in the below format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZFGt.png)

Can i get some help here please?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? You should start by casting your date as a timestamp. Let's have a look to https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-date-and-time-functions/

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your timestamp column name is time:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import * 
df2 = df1.withColumn('year',year('time')).withColumn('quarter',quarter('time')).withColumn('weekOfTheYear',weekofyear('time')).withColumn('dayOfTheWeek', dayofweek('time')).withColumn('dayofmonth',dayofmonth('time'))
```